# Proving $I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^m\dbinom{m}{k}I(0,n+m-2k)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $m$ be an integer $0\leq m\leq n$. If $I(m,n)=\int_{-1}^{1}x^mT_n(x)dx$, prove that
$$I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^m\dbinom{m}{k}I(0,n+m-2k).$$
Here $T_n(x)$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

It is easy to discuss $\int_{-1}^{1}T_n(x)dx$, but when it comes to $x^mT_n(x)$, $x=\cos\theta$ seems to be a bad way to deal with it. I've got $$I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{m-1}\theta \cos (n\theta) \sin (2\theta) d\theta.$$

Can any one prove it?

Comment: You better tell us what $T_n$ is.

Comment: Sorry $T_n(x)$ is Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $I(m,n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{m}\theta \cos (n\theta) \sin (\theta) d\theta$

But for $m$ odd one has that $$\cos^{m}\theta \cos (n\theta)=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{(m-1)/2}{m \choose k}\cos (m-2k)\theta \cos n\theta$$

Since

$2\cos (m-2k)\theta \cos n\theta=\cos(m+n-2k)+\cos(n-m+2k)=$

$=\cos(m+n-2k)+\cos(m+n-2(m-k))$, while ${m \choose k}={m \choose m-k}$ and the summation index of $m-k$ goes from $(m+1)/2$ to $m$, we get that $$I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2^m}\int_0^{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}\cos (n+m-2k)\theta \sin \theta d\theta=$$ $$=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^m\dbinom{m}{k}I(0,n+m-2k)$$

For $m$ even using that $$\cos^{m}\theta =\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^{m/2-1}2{m \choose k}\cos (m-2k)\theta +{m \choose m/2}$$ multiplying with $\cos n\theta$ and using the same method as above noting that $2\cos (m-2k)\theta\cos n\theta=\cos (n+m-2k)+\cos (n+m-2(m-k))$, we clearly get the required result in this case too!